# Can an html form submission action publish to a google pubsub topic?

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Can an html form submission action publish to a google pubsub topic directly without an intermediate application or script that is usually used to publish?
I have quickly gone through most of the pubsub decuments available at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher . However, I am unable to find answer regarding this. Can anyone familiar with pubsub be able to help me?

I'm looking for something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="https//:[PubSub Topic URL to publish]">
  <label>First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label>Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PubSub SDK is meant to be used on server side as it requires a service account (or default credentials) to initialize. You can use the REST API directly if this is just an internal application but you should not add your bearer token in client application.

Comment: It is an internal application. Only a few internal applications will be publishing to the pubsub using some forms. How this can be done?